# Adding the parent attribute to wordpress core gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to add a base element (imagine it like a WYSIWYG editor) within headings, paragraphs, images and lists are available.

I would love to use the core blocks for this. I can not have them available on the top level however. But I also can not loose the functionality of block templates.

So I am wondering, if it is possible to somehow add allowed block parents for core blocks.

A bit like I do with a custom heading element:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "name": "stof/heading",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "title": "Heading",
  "category": "stof",
  "icon": "editor-textcolor",
  "description": "Heading",
  "keywords": [
    "heading"
  ],
  "parent": ["stof/text-wrapper", "core/media-text"], // can I set this for a core/block?
  "textdomain": "stof",
  "attributes": {}
}
```

Can I set the parent via extending a block? If yes, I am not sure how I would do it.
I tried following this guide: https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/how-to-extend-existing-gutenberg-blocks-in-wordpress which did not end in anything usable. I also understand that this tutorial is quite a different scenario.

What I ended up with is this:

```
/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

/**
 * Add custom attribute for mobile visibility.
 *
 * @param {Object} settings Settings for the block.
 *
 * @return {Object} settings Modified settings.
 */
function addAttributes( settings ) {

    //check if object exists for old Gutenberg version compatibility
    if ( typeof settings.attributes !== 'undefined' ) {

        if (settings.name === 'core/list') {
            settings.attributes = Object.assign( settings.attributes, {
                parent: ['stof/text-wrapper', 'core/media-text'],

            });

        }

    }

    return settings;
}

addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'stof/list-two',
    addAttributes
);
```

Comment: Hey, i think your solution works, but it's not clear from the question. Could you mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code somehow does not work.
But I understand you want to edit existing block to be able to insert only into another block that have it allowed in template.

You can do it like:

```js
/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;

/**
 * Set paretn for core newsletter
 * @param {obj} settings 
 * @param {string} name 
 */
function addAttributes( settings, name ) {
    // Bail if not block we want to edit.
    if ( name !== 'core/list' ) {
        return settings;
    }

    // There is create new object we want to add.
    const parentObj = {
        parent: [ 'stof/text-wrapper', 'core/media-text' ],
    }

    return { ...settings, ...parentObj };
}

addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'stof/my-filter',
    addAttributes
);
```